WinUI3 ComboBox doesn't show selected value
        <ComboBox Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="Combo1"   MinWidth="500" IsDropDownOpen="True" IsEditable="False" Header="ASIO Driver selection:"
                         ItemsSource="{x:Bind Drivers}"
         SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="AsioSelChanged" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  x:DataType="local:AsioItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name1}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

The above setup creates a combobox all right, but this combobox although it does select the items, it doesn't set the text to it's selected item.
winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<winrt::tsed::AsioItem> Audio::Drivers()
{
    auto children = single_threaded_observable_vector<tsed::AsioItem>(); 
    // fill children
    ...
    ///
    auto topnv = Content().as<StackPanel>();
    auto cb = topnv.FindName(L"Combo1").as<ComboBox>();
    cb.Text(L"test"); // this doesn't work either
}

How do I tell the CombBox to do the obvious, i.e. set the selected text of the combo box to it's text?
Edit: I tried the FontFamily example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.combobox?view=windows-app-sdk-1.6. Not even this works. If I set the "DisplayMemberPath", it throws an E_UNEXPECTED exception.
    <ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo" Header="Fonts" Height="44" Width="296" 
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind fonts}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="FontFamily">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Source}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

IDL:
Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily> fonts{ get; 

};
Code:
winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily> fonts()
    {
        auto children = single_threaded_observable_vector<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily>();
        children.Append(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily(L"Arial"));
        children.Append(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily(L"Tahoma"));
        children.Append(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily(L"Calibri"));
        return children;
        }


The Text property will be active when IsEditable is true. If you want to get the text, in your case Name, you might want to use SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue:
<ComboBox
    x:Name="Combo1"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Drivers}"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    SelectedValuePath="Name">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:AsioItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Combo1.SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />


But this is another control, I want the same combobox to display the selection.

That's weird. Your code should show the selected item's Name. Can you share the code around Drivers and AsioItem?

Not even the FontFamily example in the docs work. See edit.

You can see the three options but not the one selected when the drop menu is closed, right? Might be a C++ issue since I can't repro your issue on C#.

For some reason, when I deleted and recreated the AsioItem it worked ...
